# Python Backtrader Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AAPL'

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance, back-testing, backtrader

I am trying to use the [`backtrader` package](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader) in Python 3.8 to run a backtest on `AAPL` historical stock prices obtained from Yahoo Finance using `backtrader`'s `YahooFinanceData` module.

**Problem:** The data appears to be downloaded from Yahoo Finance, but during the backtesting process, we get an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AAPL'

Any idea how we can solve this problem?

**System:**

- Mac OS X 10.15.3
- Python 3.8.0
- backtrader 1.9.74.123

**Python Code to Reproduce Error**

```
from datetime import datetime
import backtrader as bt

class SmaSignal(bt.Signal):
    param = (('period', 20), )

    def __init__(self):
        self.lines.signal = self.data - bt.ind.SMA(period=self.p.period)

data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(dataname='AAPL',
                                fromdate=datetime(2018, 1, 1),
                                todate=datetime(2018, 12, 31))
cerebro = bt.Cerebro(stdstats=False)
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.broker.setcash(1000.0)
cerebro.add_signal(bt.SIGNAL_LONG, SmaSignal)
cerebro.addobserver(bt.observers.BuySell)
cerebro.addobserver(bt.observers.Value)

print(f'Starting Portfolio Value: {cerebro.broker.getvalue():.2f}')
cerebro.run()
print(f'Final Portfolio Value: {cerebro.broker.getvalue():.2f}')
cerebro.plot(iplot=True, volume=False)
```

**Error Stack**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "02.py", line 21, in <module>
    cerebro.run()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/cerebro.py", line 1127, in run
    runstrat = self.runstrategies(iterstrat)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/cerebro.py", line 1210, in runstrategies
    data._start()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feed.py", line 203, in _start
    self.start()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feeds/yahoo.py", line 352, in start
    super(YahooFinanceData, self).start()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feeds/yahoo.py", line 94, in start
    super(YahooFinanceCSVData, self).start()
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/backtrader/feed.py", line 674, in start
    self.f = io.open(self.p.dataname, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AAPL'
```

Comment: You could download data from other providers like finnhub.io or alpha vantage and use that as input.

Answer (score 5):

I did some googling on their forum site and found [1](https://community.backtrader.com/topic/522/yahoofinancedata-filenotfounderror) and [2](https://community.backtrader.com/topic/825/error-with-test-script-on-home-page), which indicate Yahoo api has not worked for a few years. Either use a different data feed or save data as a csv file and read it in.

Answer (score 5):

The error is that the request to Yahoo API fails, and `backtrader` then falls back to trying to read local copies of the data but in a way that also fails. The Yahoo API changed a few years ago and `backtrader` hasn't been updated since then. This is a big issue as even [the tutorial example](https://www.backtrader.com/home/helloalgotrading/) is broken!

The change @mathias-thorsen mentioned in his answer was proposed to be included in `backtrader` in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/pull/401), but it was closed. `backtrader` has slowed development and a fork [`backtrader2`](https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader) is vying to be its successor. `backtrader2` found that [a difference fix](https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader/pull/67) resolved the root cause of the Yahoo API request failing. They proposed the same fix into the upstream `backtrader` in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/pull/453) and it was recently merged. With the creator gone though, there's no way to publish a new release to PyPI. `backtrader2` also cannot yet take over the PyPI namespace for `backtrader` (https://pypi.org/project/backtrader/).

So how do you install the fixed version of `backtrader` or the more updated `backtrader2` if they aren't published on PyPI? You could install the latest development version from GitHub using either

- `pip install git+https://github.com/mementum/backtrader.git#egg=backtrader`
- `pip install git+https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader.git#egg=backtrader`

There's also an issue when `backtrader` uses of the latest `matplotlib`, where the fix has been merged, but with no release. You can find similar approaches to install from source (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66871735/6068036).

Answer (score 2):

Using yfinance, you can quickly rewrite it, like that.

```
import yfinance as yf

data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=yf.download("MSFT", 
                                            start="2018-01-01", 
                                            end="2018-12-31"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Finance have changed their output recently, specifically the content type of the API response('text/csv' is expected but 'text/plain' is returned). To fix it you have to change to code in the file backtrader/feeds/yahoo.py

In line 330, replace:

```
if 'text/csv' not in ctype:
```

With:

```
if ctype not in ['text/csv', 'text/plain']:
```

There is a pull request open with backtrader to fix this in the package, but it has not been commited yet.