# ImportError Cannot import name 'warnings' from 'matplotlib.dates

Tags: matplotlib, backtrader

Alpaca backtrader plot issue: I ran into this import issue and found [this article](https://community.backtrader.com/topic/981/importerror-cannot-import-name-min_per_hour-when-trying-to-plot/8), so I applied the code, but same issue not resolved. any one can help please?

My installed matplotlib version is 3.3.1
backtrader 1.9.76.123
python 3.8.5

the entire code posted below:

```
from matplotlib.dates 

import (HOURS_PER_DAY, MIN_PER_HOUR, SEC_PER_MIN,MONTHS_PER_YEAR, 
        DAYS_PER_WEEK,SEC_PER_HOUR, SEC_PER_DAY,num2date, rrulewrapper, 
        YearLocator,MicrosecondLocator)

import alpaca_backtrader_api

import backtrader as bt

from datetime import datetime

#import matplotlib
ALPACA_API_KEY = "XXXXX"

ALPACA_SECRET_KEY = "XXXX"

ALPACA_PAPER = True

class SmaCross(bt.SignalStrategy):

def init(self):

sma1, sma2 = bt.ind.SMA(period=10), bt.ind.SMA(period=30)

crossover = bt.ind.CrossOver(sma1, sma2)

self.signal_add(bt.SIGNAL_LONG, crossover)

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

cerebro.addstrategy(SmaCross)

store = alpaca_backtrader_api.AlpacaStore( key_id=ALPACA_API_KEY,secret_key=ALPACA_SECRET_KEY,paper=ALPACA_PAPER)

if not ALPACA_PAPER:
  
  broker = store.getbroker() # or just alpaca_backtrader_api.AlpacaBroker()
  
  cerebro.setbroker(broker)
  
  DataFactory = store.getdata # or use alpaca_backtrader_api.AlpacaData
  
  data0 = DataFactory(dataname='AAPL', historical=True, fromdate=datetime(2015, 1, 1), timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Days)
  
  cerebro.adddata(data0)
  
  print('Starting Portfolio Value: %.2f' % cerebro.broker.getvalue())
  
  cerebro.run()
  
  print('Final Portfolio Value: %.2f' % cerebro.broker.getvalue())
  
  cerebro.plot()
```

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 91):

Downgrade to matplotlib 3.2.2 until the bug in backtrader is fixed.

Here is the fix pull request: https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/pull/418.

```sh
pip uninstall matplotlib  # or conda
pip install matplotlib==3.2.2
```

Comment: Does this work with Python 3.9? In my case it didn't work, I can't install this version of matplotlib.

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError using conda (miniforge/osx-arm)

Answer (score 23):

I suffered the same problem like you did, your link provided has the perfect solution. just get rid of `warnings` from `locator.py`

https://community.backtrader.com/topic/981/importerror-cannot-import-name-min_per_hour-when-trying-to-plot/8

Comment: This is the only answer that worked with Python 3.9 and Mac OS X Catalina. Find locator.py on your system and delete the 'warnings' argument from the import statement. See the post by Ch4r0n at the link given above in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't install `matplotlib==3.2.2` nor the patch without uninstalling `backtrader` first.

So, this worked for me in the end:

1. Uninstall `backtrader`:

   ```
   pip uninstall backtrader
   ```
2. Install the patch provided in [the above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66871735/12763686):

   ```
   pip install git+https://github.com/mementum/backtrader.git@0fa63ef4a35dc53cc7320813f8b15480c8f85517#egg=backtrader
   ```
3. If necessary, install `matplotlib` again:

   ```
   pip install matplotlib
   ```

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out above, the issue is addressed in [this pull request](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/pull/418) and the patch is the latest commit to master, but there hasn't been a release since 2019-05.

You can install the patched version like so:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/mementum/backtrader.git@0fa63ef4a35dc53cc7320813f8b15480c8f85517#egg=backtrader
```

You could alternatively specify the required commit in requirements.txt like so:

```
-e git+https://github.com/mementum/backtrader.git@0fa63ef4a35dc53cc7320813f8b15480c8f85517#egg=backtrader
```

…then `pip install -r requirements.txt`

After installing with either method, you can confirm the versions installed with `pip freeze`:

```sh
...
backtrader==1.9.76.123
...
```

[How to install from git](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#git)

Comment: This worked for me with python 3.9 as well. The option to add to the requirements .txt is a good tip

Comment: This is so weird. I have the exact same version of backtrader installed, yet it's still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Mac Big Sur
for me it only worked if:
Downgrade python3.9 to python 3.8
then I downgraded matplotlib==3.2.2

Answer (score 4):

For both python 3.8.x and 3.9.x, I solved the problem by using specific version of matplotlib==3.2.2

```
pip install matplotlib==3.2.2
```

By default, I used matplotlib==3.4.x version and the problem occured.

Answer (score 3):

All of the above answers are fine. The problem is *not* with `Matplotlib` though. The `Backtrader` library hasn't kept up with the `Matplotlib` updates. You can do the off-label `Backtrader` update suggested by Joel Brigate above...or you can make a simple mod to `locator.py` file (`backtrader.plot`):

Just change:

```
from matplotlib.dates import (HOURS_PER_DAY, MIN_PER_HOUR, 
    SEC_PER_MIN, MONTHS_PER_YEAR, DAYS_PER_WEEK, SEC_PER_HOUR, 
    SEC_PER_DAY, num2date, rrulewrapper, YearLocator, 
    MicrosecondLocator, warnings)
```

to:

```
from matplotlib import warnings
from matplotlib.dates import (HOURS_PER_DAY, MIN_PER_HOUR, SEC_PER_MIN,
    MONTHS_PER_YEAR, DAYS_PER_WEEK, SEC_PER_HOUR,
    SEC_PER_DAY, num2date, rrulewrapper,
    YearLocator, MicrosecondLocator)
```

You'll note that the `warnings` import now comes directly out of `matplotlib` rather than `matplotlib.dates`. This is the offending issue within `locator.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
python -m pip uninstall matplotlib
python -m pip uninstall backtrader
python -m pip install backtrader
python -m pip install matplotlib==3.2.2
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I could **not** install matplotlib==3.2.2 with **python 3.9** .

Here is how did I fix this issue:

```
$ pip uninstall backtrader
$ pip install git+https://github.com/mementum/backtrader.git@0fa63ef4a35dc53cc7320813f8b15480c8f85517#egg=backtrader
```

Reference:
[Github: Fix ImportError from matplotlib.dates
#418](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/pull/418)

Answer (score 0):

@laffuste solution of downgrading to version 3.2.2 of matplotlib solved the issue for me. PR to fix the issue is still open, you can also follow [this forum](https://community.backtrader.com/topic/2784/cannot-import-name-warnings-from-matplotlib-dates) for more info on the problem:

Answer (score 0):

Mac Big Sur.  I did the same:  python 3.8.5, uninstall matplotlib, install matplotlib==3.2.2

I'm new at this so I first tried the easy way, through anaconda.org, but could not find version 3.2.2.  Then tried it from the Jupyter notebook with conda install... didn't work.  I finally did it straight through terminal, which worked fine.

Comment: Please provide the exact terminal commands you used. Remember to format as code.

Comment: pip install matplotlib==3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install matplotlib==3.2.2 after installing freetype in a Mac with Apple silicon CPU.

```
brew install freetype
# then
pip install matplotlib==3.2.2 
# finally
pip install backtrader
```